# Cross Product: If $\textbf{v}\times\textbf{w}=\textbf{0}$ then either $\textbf{w}=\textbf{0}$ or $\textbf{v}=c\textbf{w}$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\textbf{v}\times\textbf{w}=\textbf{0}$ then either $\textbf{w}=\textbf{0}$ or $\textbf{v}=c\textbf{w}$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$

How to prove it?

Edit:   Assume both $\textbf{w}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are not equal to $\textbf{0}$.
It can be proved that $||\textbf{v}\times\textbf{w}||=\sqrt{||\textbf{v}^2||\textbf{w}||^2-(\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{w})^2}$, so  $||\textbf{v}||^2||\textbf{w}||^2-(\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{w})^2=0 $ then $ ||\textbf{v}||||\textbf{w}||=|\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{w}|$, so the angle between $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{w}$ is 0 or $\pi$, thus $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{w}$ are parallel, so $\textbf{v}=c\textbf{w}$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it right?

Comment: Look at how the cross product is defined with angles and norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$

Also , $\vec u \times \vec w= \vert {\vec v} \vert \vert{\vec w}\vert \sin{\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them .

If it's given that  $\vec u \times \vec w = 0$ ,then either of the $\vert {\vec v} \vert$ or $\vert {\vec w} \vert$ is 0 , or $\sin(\theta)=0$ , which means the vectors are parellel to each other , and hence one of them is a scalar multiple of the other vector , which can be stated as $\vec v = c \vec w$, for some $c\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: You should not answer low quality posts